# Fixed size Stack Java

Tags: java, stack

I want to create a fixed-size stack and truncate the stack when is full. For this already exists a approach in [Creating a fixed-size Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727919/creating-a-fixed-size-stack), but I do not want to implement a class.

It is possible to do something like this?

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String push(String item) {
        if (this.size() == FIXED_SIZE) {
            //truncate()
        }
        return super.push(item);
    }
};
```

And the rest of the stack methods remain the same?

Comment: Do you want to truncate or clear?

Comment: I'm sorry, truncate. How can I do this?

Comment: truncate what?The element doesn't get added

Comment: A "fixed size stack" is an array and a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I found in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). I did not use or tested it. So I am not sure how this would work out. Because `removeElementAt()` is inherited from Vector class, and I am hoping that `removeElementAt(0)`, will still remove the element at the bottom.

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String push(String item) {
        if (this.size() == FIXED_SIZE) {
            this.removeElementAt(0);
        }
        return super.push(item);
    }
};
```

And also I am assuming that, what you meant by truncate is to remove the first-in element currently in the list, if you just want to reject the new coming element, you can just return `null`.

Comment: It is precisely this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
 Public class TruncatedStack<T> extends FixedStack<T>
 {         
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     @Override
     public String push(String item) {
     if (this.top == size) {
        this.top = -1;
     return super.push(item);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this off the top of my head (untested).  As mentioned in the comments, a fixed size stack is simply an array with a counter to keep track of the top.

```
public class FixedSizeStack {
  int top, numElements;
  int[] baseArray;

  public FixedSizeStack(int maxSize) {
    top = 0;
    numElements = 0;
    baseArray = new int[maxSize];
  }

  public void push(int num) {
    baseArray[top] = num;
    top = (top+1) % baseArray.length;
    numElements++;
  }

  public int pop(int num) {
    if(numElements == 0) return null;  //or throw exception--you've removed too many elements!
    numElements--;

    top = (top == 0) ? (baseArray.length - 1) : (top - 1);
    return baseArray[top];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you are almost exactly right. You just need to do a `this.remove(0)` and then you're done.

```
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>(){
    @Override
    public String push(String item) {
        if (this.size() == FIXED_SIZE) {
            this.remove(0)
        }
        return super.push(item);
    }
};
```