# A little save class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, save

I have a little save class for 4 array list to make a `ctrl + z` thing. The problem is that sometimes the class gives an empty array back. But I always give full arrays to the class- can anyone help? I tried to find out the problem but the only thing i found out was that when I first call "`addtempsave`" two times and then call "`getlastsave`" then one time "`addtempsave`" and then one time "`getlastsave`". Then the method gives a empty `ArrayList` back.

This is the Class:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Undo {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> tempsaves = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

    public Undo() {

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void addtempsave(ArrayList<Integer> mapLetters, ArrayList<Integer> gegnerLetters, ArrayList<Background> bgFinish, ArrayList<Background> bgFinish2) {

        ArrayList<Object> save = new ArrayList<Object>();

        ArrayList<Integer> ml = (ArrayList<Integer>) mapLetters.clone();
        ArrayList<Integer> gl = (ArrayList<Integer>) gegnerLetters.clone();
        ArrayList<Background> b1 = (ArrayList<Background>) bgFinish.clone();
        ArrayList<Background> b2 = (ArrayList<Background>) bgFinish2.clone();

        save.add(0,  ml);
        save.add(1,  gl);
        save.add(2,  b1);
        save.add(3,  b2);


        if(tempsaves.size() > 100) {
            tempsaves.remove(0);
        }

        tempsaves.add(save);
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> getlastsave() {

        if(tempsaves.size() == 1) {

            return tempsaves.get(0);

        }
        else {
            tempsaves.remove(tempsaves.size() - 1);

            return tempsaves.get(tempsaves.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i load the old things is that ok like that ?

```
mapLetters.clear();
bgFinish.clear();
bgFinish2.clear();
gegnerLetters.clear();
UpdateArrayList tempsave =  backwart.getlastsave();
mapLetters = tempsave.ml;
gegnerLetters = tempsave.gl;
bgFinish = tempsave.b1;
bgFinish2 = tempsave.b2;
```

Comment: Post your code here. Not on some 3rd party website.

Answer (score 0):

```
tempsaves.remove(tempsaves.size() - 1);//removing it first
return tempsaves.get(tempsaves.size() - 1);//then trying to return this
```

i think you need to save the content into some object first

then remove it and return saved content

Comment: no the last save must be remoed with tempsaves.remove(tempsaves.size() - 1); then the size from tempsaves gose down one so i return the list befor the last.

Comment: why are you checking `tempsaves.get(tempsaves.size() - 1).isEmpty()`?

Comment: soory it was only a test

Comment: then your code looks good, unless you are not making any mistake in calling those functions, i mean order in which you call them, also check if proper data gets stored every time you add something to temp

Comment: additional things you mentioned are also fine, what I am saying is, you might be calling `getlastsave()` number of times which is making main list empty(less likely the chance) second is the content you are putting in list are itself not getting populated

Comment: the calls of the methods a right and in the right nummber. The contend is right too so i dont know the problem. But after the case above ther comes a emty array list.

Answer (score 0):

The condition below is dangerous and will throw Exception, should the tempsaves be empty or of size=1 (when the first element is empty)

```
if(tempsaves.get(tempsaves.size() - 1).isEmpty()) {
        return tempsaves.get(tempsaves.size() - 2);
}
```

And in general instead of coding against the empty `ArrayList` case (which as you write is unexpected and shouldn't happen) I'd dig deeper, trying to understand what causes the problem. Try to identify the sequence of inputs that causes the issue (in the end there is nothing undeterministic in what you're trying to do) and take it from there.

Also personally I'd consider using a `Stack` instead of `ArrayList`, as it seems a much better match to what you're trying to achieve (and if you're looking for the fixed size stack look here: [Creating a fixed-size Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727919/creating-a-fixed-size-stack)).

Also to help with debugging have you considered wrapping those 4 arraylists into a single `Update` class, i.e.:

```
public class Update {

    final ArrayList<Integer> ml;
    final ArrayList<Integer> gl;
    final ArrayList<Background> b1;
    final ArrayList<Background> b2;

    public Update(ArrayList<Integer> ml, ArrayList<Integer> gl, ArrayList<Background> b1, ArrayList<Background> b2) {
        this.ml = (ArrayList<Integer>)ml.clone();
        this.gl = (ArrayList<Integer>)gl.clone();
        this.b1 = (ArrayList<Background>)b1.clone();
        this.b2 = (ArrayList<Background>)b2.clone();
    }

}
```

Then you can have an easy to manage `Stack<Update>` collection and the `Update` class itself can be easily unit tested, printed etc?

Comment: I've added the example of the Update class, hope that's helpful. In general wrapping all 4 lists into a single object will allow you access them by name (and not to worry about indexes in the ArrayList, i.e. were my `bgFinish` values 3rd or 4th on the list, but simply calling `update.b1` (or even more meaningful name would be better :). Also you avoid this misterious and unsafe conversion from Object to ArrayList this way.

Comment: Very valid question on `Stack` Overflow ;) 

You can find theoretical basics (and details) on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type), though unless you've got evening to spare, I'd suggest digging into the Java API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html and some basic tutorial, i.e. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/stack_pop.htm first.

Comment: above in the question i post how i open old saves can that be the problem ? and no the methode isnt called truth the lists are cleared

Comment: Check what does the `getlastsave` returns (i.e. print the whole list and the returned result) or even better try to use your IDE debugger to see the state of the `tempsaves` list/stack. This will allow you to find your whether it's a problem with what you insert or return. Good luck with the debugging.

Comment: i always say in the top wher the problem comes up ... thats what i finde out with debugging but i dont know how to fix ....

Comment: i tryed out the stack thing and all the other things but dont finde the mistake how is allready ther -.- and the methode is only called with full array i dont know how that can be -.-

Comment: Since the code you posted looks fine (given certain assumptions), the problem must be in the way you initialize your `tempsaves` collection. Do you have a full test scenario which would replicate the problem?

Comment: So i test wether the function is caled with a emty arraylist but thats not the fact. addtempsave() is allways called with full arralists. The Problem comes up when i first call the funtkion addtempsave() for one or more times, then call getlastsave() then again addtempsave() and when i call getlastsave() again i get an emty array.