# Javascript - How can i force an array to have a specific amount of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack

Is there an easy way to make an array have a specific amount of element.
In the sense that if you push more into it, it overides the first element.

for example i want an array to only contain 2 elements. if i push a third element, it should overwrite the earliest element (the first in).
Like a stack.

Comment: While it may be possible, it's not advisable. It's much wiser to use your own data structure (that uses an array internally) to accomplish this.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727919/creating-a-fixed-size-stack
<br/> Make something similar to this in javascript

Comment: a stack would remove the first element and pushes on top.

Comment: You will have to use Array subclassing to create a new array which has it's own push method in it's prototype to suppress / shadow the push method of  the Array.prototype. It's own push method should take care of the shifting out the item at index 0 operation once the length reaches to a certain value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter and use the modulo with the wanted length for inserting.

```js
function push(array, length) {
    var counter = 0;
    return function (value) {
        array[counter % length] = value;
        counter++;
    };
}

var array = [],
    pushToArray = push(array, 2);

pushToArray(1);
console.log(array);

pushToArray(2);
console.log(array);

pushToArray(3);
console.log(array);

pushToArray(4)
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So as i have commented above you might do this by array sub-classing. The following snippet introduces a new Array structure with two new methods as `last` and `push`. However our new `push` shadows the real `push` method of the `Array.prototype`. The new `push` takes the first argument as the limit to the array length such as `[1,2,3].push(4,"a","b","c")` will limit the length to 4 and the result would be `[3,"a","b","c"]`. The return value will be the deleted elements in an array as we are using `splice` under the hood.

```js
function SubArray(...a) {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(a, SubArray.prototype);
  return a;
}
SubArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
SubArray.prototype.last = function() {
  return this[this.length - 1];
};
SubArray.prototype.push = function(lim,...a){
  Array.prototype.push.apply(this,a);
  return this.splice(0,this.length-lim);
};

myArray = new SubArray(1,2,3);
myArray.last();
myArray.push(4,"a","b","c");
console.log(myArray);
```